Input Example for Load Balancing: Greedy vs Ordered Scheduling Algorithm
I'm working on a problem involving load balancing across three machines. I need to find an input example (a list of job sizes) where the greedy scheduling algorithm produces a strictly lower makespan than the ordered scheduling algorithm.
For context:
The ordered scheduling algorithm assigns jobs sequentially to machines in a fixed order (e.g., Machine 1, Machine 2, Machine 3, then repeats).
The greedy scheduling algorithm assigns each job to the machine with the least current load.
Here's the type of input I'm looking for:
The input should consist of at least 3 jobs, we have 3 machines for example.
The greedy algorithm should produce a better (lower) makespan than the ordered algorithm.
Can someone help me construct such an input example? Any explanation of why the input works would also be appreciated. Thank you!

Have you tried coding those algorithms and generating random inputs and testing if one of them is such an example?

Also, one could find an example by hand. With 3 jobs, it is not possible, but 4 jobs can do the trick. It is not that hard to find it you you search a bit.
